# How to track a phone call duration using progressive web app?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

right now i am working on PWA, using HTML5 i can able to access Phone dial pad [ `<a href="tel:+496170961709">96170961709</a>`]. but, we need to track phone cal duration . in android there is an API called Broadcast receiver , by using that i android we can track phone call duration.

but , is it possible to track phone call duration in PWA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if its a PWA, its still a web app running in browser and [limited to web standards](https://whatwebcando.today/). 
Only thing you can track with pure web solution is to know if the [network is active or not](https://whatwebcando.today/online-state.html).

However, you can achieve this with an additional Android service(has to be installed independently in the device) which can broadcast the same info in a web socket, which can be received in PWA. Hybrid solution like this are the only way you can get native functionality that aren't available in web yet.

Comment: Thanks for your response. can you please refer any additional Android Service , which are possible to integrate with PWA.

Comment: You have to create a Android service with the broad cast receiver to get the call details and send a broadcast message via websocket to PWA (PWA will be running web socket client, listening in a particular port in localhost, while Android service will send the data using web-socket server in the same port) . There is no out of box solution that is ready made to use with PWA. You have to create your own Android service and deploy it to all the devices where your PWA will be used.

Comment: Hi Anand, i have small doubt , i have 3 separate PWA apps . all have calling functionality. you told that,  to get phone call status we need to create Android service and we need to install in the device. but, i need to install only once or i need to install 3 android services for all 3 PWA apps in the same device.

Comment: @KKishoreKumarReddy Just 1 for any number of clients(PWAs) which needs the same functionality. As long as you have one Android service communicating the required information in a web socket in the way you need, any number of PWA can connect to it.

Comment: i have used intent for calling Android app. thanks for your idea. i have implemented and now i can call and Track call logs using PWA Application [with help of Android app] .

Answer (score 2):

No. Browsers don't provide any APIs to access call status/logs.